# EF6 CF Postal Code validation Starts with ZERO "0"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I already have a validation using EF6.

```
[MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "{0} Code should have at least {1} character length.")]
[DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
[StringLength(9)]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

The address is: 156 Main St
Belfast, ME 04915, USA

Zip Code starts with zero

But when MVC validate the zip code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9C10.png)

Then it became like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWJ7H.jpg)

How can I allow Zero in the inputbox??

This is how I generate my Control

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "9", id = "txtZip", placeholder = "Zip Code", aria_invalid = true, type = "text" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zip,"", new { @class = "validation-danger" })
```

Comment: How are you generating the control for `Zip` in the view?

Comment: I think you can omit DataType.PostalCode and validate it using a simple Regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is the AddressModel:

```
public class AddressModel
{
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "{0} Code should have at least {1} character length.")]
    [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
    [StringLength(9)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the Controller members:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult EEIndex()
    {
        AddressModel am = new AddressModel();


        return View(am);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EEIndex(AddressModel am)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //is valid
            var valid = true;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Here is the view:

This will retain the zero.

```
@model Testy2.Controllers.AddressModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EEIndex</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @*@using (Html.BeginForm("EEIndex", "Home", new { UserId = "5" }, FormMethod.Post))*@
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EEIndex", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "9", id = "txtZip", placeholder = "Zip Code", aria_invalid = true, type = "text" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zip, "", new { @class = "validation-danger" })

            <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
        }

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```